# Python Creating element of a dict conditionally

Tags: python

please could someone help me with this?
I'm trying to use a short version of checking if b doesn't exist, then asign ''
or None, but I'm missing something

```
>test = dict(s = b if b else '')
>NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Edited: I know that b is not defined, instead I want to find a way to 
create a dict with a value if exist or '' if doesn't exist, I want to do that
in a short way..Thanks

Comment: Python doesn't know what you are referring to because `b` hasn't been defined at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "if the value exists"? How are you *getting to the point in your program where `s` is created*, without *knowing* whether `b` has been defined yet?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined any variable named `b`.  This looks like it may be an XY problem though.  What are you actually trying to do?  Insert in to a dictionary?  Create a new one with just one element?

Comment: I don't need a function for this... Thanks anyway

Comment: I want Create a new one, and it can have more than one element, but first I want to get a short way to do it with one element to understand...

Answer (score 1):

You should use **dictionary comprehension**

```
d = {key: value for (key, value) in sequence if condition}
```

Also the comment of BlackVegetable is true, you haven't defined `b`, so python cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted this earlier, then deleted it, but I tested it and it works:

```
dict(s=b) if b else dict(s='')`
```

If `b` is `None`, the above line will work.  That is what I understood from the question, you want to check if b exists.  Then if it does, you want to set the key as such, otherwise as ''.

Comment: `dict(s = b if b else None)` should also work. I deleted my answer because it will still break if `b` is not defined, as others have pointed out.